# Jupyterhub K8s - Issue with Changing User from Jovyan to NB_USER

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

```
Everything works well until we wanted to set the NB_USER to the logged in user. When changed the config to run as root and start.sh as default cmd, getting the below error in the log and the container is failing to start. Any help is highly appreciated
```

After running the container as root, getting the below log for the error:
Set username to: user1
Relocating home dir to /home/user1
mv: cannot move '/home/jovyan' to '/home/user1': Device or resource busy

```
Here is the config.yaml
singleuser:
defaultUrl: "/lab"
uid: 0
fsGid: 0
hub:
extraConfig: |
c.KubeSpawner.args = ['--allow-root']
c.Spawner.cmd = ['start.sh','jupyterhub-singleuser']
def notebook_dir_hook(spawner):
spawner.environment = {'NB_USER':spawner.user.name, 'NB_UID':'1500'}
c.Spawner.pre_spawn_hook = notebook_dir_hook
from kubernetes import client
def modify_pod_hook(spawner, pod):
pod.spec.containers[0].security_context = client.V1SecurityContext(
privileged=True,
capabilities=client.V1Capabilities(
add=['SYS_ADMIN']
)
)`enter code here`
return pod
c.KubeSpawner.modify_pod_hook = modify_pod_hook
```